# Why my JVM has so many old char and string?

Tags: java, jvm

`jmap -histo {pid}` shows the following result:

```
 num     #instances         #bytes  class name
----------------------------------------------
   1:       4787259     1007093680  [C
   2:       6049019      191502048  [B
   3:        198580      125701976  [I
   4:       5212228      125093472  java.lang.String
```

While run `jmap -histo:live {pid}` shows the following result:

```
 num     #instances         #bytes  class name
----------------------------------------------
   1:        463375      140980752  [C
   2:          9832       63080312  [I
   3:        563438       31161448  [B
   4:        461206       11068944  java.lang.String
```

You can see that there are lots of Char and String are not live but still occupy heap memory. Is this normal or do I need to concern? I hope JVM can clean up some useless String to save memory, as I am pretty sure all these Strings are different and won't be used again and no need to keep in memory for future reuse purpose.

I mainly want to know the difference between `jmap -histo: live` and `jmap -histo`, there are over 1000M of Char in `jmap -histo` but only 140M in `jmap -histo:live`, where are the other 860M Chars? and why they are't be GC? When will these Chars be GC? How can I make them immediately GC to save memory?

Comment: Well, there's one for every name of every method and class in your code...

Comment: Why you have so many strings really depends on what your application is doing. You can try adding the `-XX:+UseStringDeduplication` GC option, which can help reduce the number of byte and char arrays, if there's a lot of duplication. This only kicks in with a full GC, and not all GCs support the feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @boneill points out, under the hood `jmap -histo:live` performs a full GC ... to determine what objects are live.  And `jmap -histo` ... doesn't.

> Why my JVM has so many old char and string?
>
> Is this normal or do I need to concern?

It is hard to say.  There is insufficient evidence.

But, without other evidence, I'd say "not concerning".

> where are the other 860M Chars?

First of all `[C` doesn't mean `Char`.  It means `char[]`.

Where are they?  Well my reading is that they are unreachable.  (Not live).  They are *candidates* for garbage collection.

> ... and why they aren't be GC?

Because the GC hasn't collected them yet.

Java garbage collection is ... complicated.  Many of the collectors are generational meaning that they split the heap into new and old object spaces.  The new space is collected frequently.  The old space is collected infrequently.  So if most of those objects have been tenured to the old space, they may life a relatively long time after they have become unreachable.

That is one possible explanation.

> When will these Chars be GC?

When the old space is collected.  Probably.

> How can I make them immediately GC to save memory?

You **could** call `System.gc()` to ask the JVM to run a (typically) full garbage collection. But ...

1. the JVM may **ignore** that request entirely,
2. it might not run a **full** GC (that's possibly implementation dependent),
3. even if the objects are collected, you most likely **won't save any actual memory**.

Why don't you save memory?  Because the JVM hangs on to the free space it got back ... ready to allocate new objects.  So the memory is not returned to the OS for other applications to use.   (There is some complicated logic for heap resizing, but as a rule the JVM gives back memory *reluctantly*; i.e. only after a number of full GC cycles.)

Finally, calling `System.gc()` in your application code is bad for performance ... in most circumstances.  There are other Q&As that explain why.

Comment: Doesn't the `:live` option force a full GC? I've generally seen this behavior.

Comment: Thank you! Quite clear. It must wait for a full GC to collect old objects, but as most of my objects are different, I want them to be GC immediately after release, so I will increase the young generation ratio. I don't care GC times, but do care memory usage.

Comment: Well ... Java probably is the wrong language for you.  Java is NOT designed with minimization of memory utilization as a main goal.  (But look at https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/346)

Comment: Looking at real life applications, giving back memory rarely happens in nontrivial applications, regardless of the programming language. That’s why operating systems counteract by virtualizing memory and, in case of Linux, even overcommitting memory. In Java, it’s rather easy to enforce earlier collection at the expense of CPU time; just set a lower maximum heap size.